# Good approach to switch database for Test mode / Sand box mode : Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, distributed-system

I am working on an app where I now need to add `test mode` or `sandbox mode` features like Stripe provides in the dashboard. In this feature, when the user turned the test mode on, the user can test the functionality and can create dummy data in the same login session/token.

I have tried to use the Rails 6 feature to use multiple databases but have a few questions:

- is it good to switch the connection in production for test mode even we will not have many test requests?
- will it be good to have a separate instance for test mode with the test subdomain? in this case how we should manage the login sessions? should we copy data to the test the database? will it be good and common practice?

I only can manage to implement this if I have user data in the test database so that when I switch database connection system will not send an unauthenticated response.

Note:

- for login and user update, it will use the primary database all time and for other actions, it will use the test_mode database. I am doing this by `skip_around_action` in a specific controller.
- We are doing this so that when the user turned off test mode, it will update the primary database and the next request will use the primary database as per `around_action` logic

Here is my current code in application_controller.rb:

```
    around_action :setup_db_connection
    def setup_db_connection
      database_key = (user.test_mode?) ? :test_mode : :primary
      ActiveRecord::Base.connected_to(database: database_key) do
        yield
      end
    end
```

`test_mode` database key has test database configuration in `database.yml` and similarly for `primary` database key. Both are completely two different databases.

Can anyone please tell me if I am going in to correct direction? Any help or thought will be appriciated. Thank you in advance!!!!

Comment: "in the same login session/token" - testmode API tokens in Stripe are explicitly different from livemode tokens, though. Else how does the API know in which mode to create records?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thank you for the quick response. But how Stripe is managing test mode while the user is logged in? Is it using predefined tokens when user is enabling test mode for next ownerd requests?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "how do they manage" and "is it using predefined tokens". There's a page in the dashboard where you can see your API tokens. If you toggle testmode on, you'll see a different set of tokens

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Sorry for my wrong question about `how do they manage` I got your point about having two different tokens. I will discuss this approach. Do you suggest implementing test mode with connection switching on production considering fewer requests?

Comment: I personally would store everything in the same database, so you have no switching and don't need to sync user data. And make sure to mark all objects that can be in test mode with `testmode=true/false`

Answer (score 1):

You should just create an additional environment as this is the exact problem that they are designed to solve.

Rails just ships preconfigured with development, test and production as thats the bare minimum you can get by with. You can actually have an unlimeted number of environments.

So lets say you want to create an enviroment named `staging` which closely matches your production environment. You can start by copying the productions settings:

```
cp app/environments/production.rb app/environments/staging.rb
```

And then just setup an additional hash in your `database.yml` and credentials files.

```
staging:
  <<: *default
  database: my_app_staging
```

You can then set the environment by using the `RAILS_ENV` env var or the command line arguments when starting the Rails server. Your staging environment can be run for example in a separate Heroku application made available on a subdomain. If you're using Heroku or some other SAAS platform a hobby tier will often be sufficient for staging.

When it comes to data you can either work on a set of dummy data generated by wiping and seeding or regularily wipe the staging database with a backup from your production database.

I would not consider using a "test mode switch" a good idea as it makes far to easy to inadvertantly mess things up. Using a separate environment lets you use a completely different set of credentials as well so you won't accentially do something like create a real credit card charge or destroy data on third party services. Sandboxes should be isolated.

Comment: A test mode switch has its benefits (and it works great for Stripe). One does have to exercise a great deal of caution, though, that's true.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev If you have to collaborate with marketoids or other non-technicals you want to hide all the pointy tools.

Comment: @max Thank you for your detailed answer. I will discuss your approach.